# SSL not showing secure for the first time

Tags: php, apache, ssl

Yesterday, I purchased an **SSL Certificate** from **Comodo**. The **SSL** is installed properly on my sub domain but it shows grey bar when I visit the site for first time.

After when I refresh the page it will show secure with green bar.

What's the exact problem?

Comment: Witch web server you use?

Comment: apache web server

Comment: Try in your root (public_html) folder in file .htaccess write this: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

Comment: Run your domain through https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html and see if it highlights any issues.

Answer (score -2):

Try in your root (public_html) folder in file .htaccess and write this (If file not in then create file make sure you don't name the file only extension (.htaccess)):

## Rewrite Rule

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

RewriteRule (.*) https://www.YourDomain.com/$1 [R]

Note: If not working above then you should make sure that your mod_rewrite is ON...

Thanks

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense given the described problem.